# Trigonometric Equation $\cos^{2}{x} - \sin{x} = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Hi I tried everything I know with this equation but, I can not solve it.

$$\cos^{2}{x} - \sin{x} = 0$$

I know it has a solution because I made a graph and it cuts the $x$ axis.

Do you have advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn this into a polynomial using the hint @AnginaSeng gave:

$\cos^2 x - \sin x = 0$

$1 - \sin^2 x  - \sin x = 0$

Now let $y = \sin x$:

$1 - y^2 - y = 0$

This should be more solvable. Solve for $y$, then use $y$ to solve for $x$

Comment: Thanks, I do not saw that...

Answer (score 3):

$\cos^2x = 1-\sin^2x$. (This is a useful formula to know, it's a simple proof from $\sin^2x+\cos^2x = 1$.)

Making the substitution, we get $1-\sin^2x-\sin x=0$, and rearranging gets us $\sin^2x+\sin x -1 = 0$. We have a quadratic in $\sin x$. Solving gets us $\sin x = \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$, but the only valid solution is $\sin x = \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ since the other gets a number not within the range of the sine function (i.e. $\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}\notin[-1,1]$).

We use the inverse sine function to get the value of $x$. $$\sin^{-1} \left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) \approx \boxed{38.17^{\circ}}$$

Comment: Thanks, I do not saw that...